# How to replace wordpress default text editor (TinyMCE) with a custom one.

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I'm on a project that requires me to replace the WordPress text editor(TinyMCE) with a custom one. I've googled it several times but I've not seen a way to make this happen.

Does anyone here have a clear guide on how I can make this happen?

I'd appreciate your guide.

Thanks.